# using insert() method to insert DateTime value with PHP Doctrine\DBAL 2

Tags: php, database, datetime, doctrine-orm, dbal

How can i pass PHP's **DateTime** object as a value for database field using **Doctrine\DBAL**?

***$DB** is a **Doctrine\DBAL\Connection** instance.*

```
$DB->insert('table_name', [
    'field' => new \DateTime(),
]);

// Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

The code above is not working and documentation is scarce.

I knew for sure that you can provide **DateTime** objects directly using another DBAL methods, is it possible to do this with **insert()**?

Comment: Solution found. Just pass third argument array('datetime') to the insert() method. Use 'datetime' for DateTime, PDO::PARAM_STR for strings and PDO::PARAM_INT for integers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$DB->insert('table_name', [
    'foo'   => 'foo',
    'bar'   => 17,
    'field' => new \DateTime(),
], [
    PDO::PARAM_STR,
    PDO::PARAM_INT,
    'datetime',
]);
```

Did the trick! ))

Comment: What about the order of the elements in the first array?  I presume when array of key-value pairs is declared right as function argument, the order of the keys will match the order of them being declared, however what if key-value pair array is created dynamically by some other function?